# How to set a default value to ng-options in case of nested json data angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, nested, angularjs-ng-options

I wanted to set a default value to my ng-options by using ng-init, ng-model, etc. I am using dependable dropdowns. My code is following:

```
 <select id="country" ng-model="statessource" ng-disabled="!type2"  ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedCountry()">
                    <option value='' selected>Select Country</option>   
                </select>

<select id="state" ng-disabled="!statessource"  ng-model="citiessource"   ng-options="state for (state,city) in statessource"
                ng-change="GetSelectedState()"  >
                    <option value=''>Select State</option>
                </select>
```

with some data like this:

```
$scope.countries = {
    'USA': {
        'IL': { 'CHICAGO': ['60633', '60646', '60653', '60656', '60607', '60632', '60643', '60652', '60620', '60612', '60661', '60624', '60634', '60601', '60827', '60644', '60631', '60630'] },
    }
}
```

I want to set default value USA in Country dropdown. How should i do this. Please suggest me.

Comment: where is "statessource" object?

Comment: You are asking ng-options to repeat over statessource but want it to select some value which is not part of statessource?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided the full code here, according to code you have posted,
You have too many mistakes in your code.

Define another `$scope` variable which is having the default object selected named "USA". You can do this like following:

```
$scope.countries = {
    'USA': {
      'IL': {
        'CHICAGO': ['60633', '60646', '60653', '60656', '60607', '60632', '60643', '60652', '60620', '60612', '60661', '60624', '60634', '60601', '60827', '60644', '60631', '60630']
      },
    }
  }
  $scope.selected = $scope.countries["USA"]; // this needs to be added
```

And your view part will look like this:

```
 <select id="state" ng-disabled="!countries" ng-model="selected" 
    ng-options="state for (state,city) in countries" ng-change="GetSelectedState()">
    <option value=''>Select State</option>
  </select>
```

And a working [*Plunker*](http://plnkr.co/edit/7NtP3cUWrgjx10CK29ly?p=preview)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ng-init** like this to set default value for **ng-option**.

```
   <select id="state" 
       ng-disabled="!statessource"
       ng-model="citiessource"
       ng-init=" citiessource = countries[0]"  
       ng-options="state for (state,city) in statessource"
       ng-change="GetSelectedState()">

    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value by modifying `citiessource` variable. So to set the default value as `USA` you need to `$scope.citiessoruce = 'USA'`.